# How jvm checks a class is loaded or not when a class is used first time

Tags: java, classloader, classloading

**Question**

when  jvm runs following code

```
MyObject o=new MyObject() //first access MyObject
```

we know jvm will starting load class of MyObject, but i wonder how jvm know MyObject is not loaded.

**Motivation**

i wonder to know because if jvm runs these codes

```
public class Main{
  public static void main(){
     ClassLoader myLoader = new ClassLoader(null) {
            @Override
            protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
                // omitted here
            }
        }
     myLoader.loadClass("MyObject"); //#1
     MyObject o=new MyObject() //#2
  }
}
```

we knows that without #1, MyObject will be loaded by classloader of class Main,but with #1,will class of MyObject loaded at #2, and how jvm makes judges?

Comment: I believe this depends on the internal workings of the JVM, though I may be mistaken about this.

Comment: Short version: "Keep track of the classes" is part of the JVM's job, and each JVM writer has to decide how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `ClassLoader` keeps a list of the classes it has loaded so far.

If two different `ClassLoader` load a class of the same name, these are treated by the runtime as two separate unrelated classes. That is useful because it allows different versions of the same class to coexist at runtime. For instance, we can deploy several web applications developed by different teams into the same JVM, each with its own libraries, freeing the developers of the various applications from coordinating the versions of the libraries they use.

In your case, if we do `new MyObject()` in class `Main`, the class loader that loaded class `Main` is asked to load class `MyObject`. That's the system `ClassLoader`, which knowns nothing of your `myLoader`. Therefore, the system class loader will load class `MyObject` again.

You can verify this by adding a static initializer to MyObject:

```
class MyObject {
    static {
        System.out.println("class MyObject has been loaded");
    }
}
```

Comment: thx man, I did that, MyObject is loaded twice. I suppose jvm just ask related context's classloader